How to upload an image using a file input from my website, to my google cloud storage
I am currently building a website within react and apollo v3/graphQL.
It is my understanding that this version of apollo does not have the native software to allow for file uploads by itself.
I am currently working on the front-end, and am using apollo-upload-client.
const uploadLink = createUploadLink({
  uri: '/graphql',
  headers: {
    'Apollo-Require-Preflight': 'true'
  }
});

My understanding is that this is what is needed for the front end. Then I need some sort of library for the back end. I decided to go with graphql-upload.
Every documentation I see, says to use commonJS syntax to require ('graphql-upload').
However, in my VS terminal, it throws an error saying that there is no general index, and that one must do a deep import (which is ecmas syntax).
Im not quite sure what to do here unfortunately.
Ive tried adding type:module to my package.json and converting everything to import/export statements but it did not work.
If anyone has any advice, or even a simpler method. All I am trying to do is upload my item images to my google cloud storage, so that I may save the URL within my image field of my item model to be able to retrieve the images for each item.
I have tried reading as many documents as I could, but nothing seems to help and/or work sadly.
